# Como usar o Scrollview do Android via código Java?

Tags: android, rolamento

No xml é fácil usar, mas estou fazendo um formulário dinâmico e não está funcionando. Estou fazendo algo mais ou menos assim:

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
```

Daí dentro do onCreate() eu uso ele:

```
scroll.addView(activity_main);
setContentView(scroll);
```

Mas está dando erro. setar o LayoutParams nele também não funcioan.

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar seu layout em .xml, você precisa infla-lo em uma `View`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View viewExemplo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seu_layout, null);
scrollView.addView(viewExemplo);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Você pode criar um xml e chamá-lo de scrollview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Via código, você obtém o container que irá receber as views.**

```
View scrollView = LayoutInflater.from([contexto aqui]).inflate(R.layout.scrollview, null);

LinearLayout mLinearContainer = (LinearLayout)scrollView .findViewById(R.id.linearContent);

 // nesse mLinearContainer  você adiciona as views
```

Comment: Não tinha reparado que você usaria esse layout na Activity, então basta fazer setContentView(R.layout.scrollview)   e fazer o find diretamente, sem precisar de LayoutInflater.from([contexto aqui]).inflate(R.layout.scrollview, null);  Lembre-se que ScrollView deve ter apenas um filho direto e deve ser ViewGroup, ou seja, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc.